# js/ajax POST without submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I want to preface this with, "I'm a total noob so please explain like I'm five."  I've looked at a lot of answers to this common question but I was unable to find a suitable answer to my particular problem.  Below is the scripty bit in question.  Currently, the user inputs an order number.  This gets sent via the ajax call to a php processor script.  The processor script validates the order number and then sends data back.  If data !="NO" we get sent to a new page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function resetTextFields()
{
    $("#orderNum").val("");                
}

function onSuccess(data, status)
{
    resetTextFields();
    // Notify the user the new post was saved
    $("#message").fadeIn(2000);
    data = $.trim(data);
    if(data != "NO")
    {
        location.href="labOrders.php";
    }
    else
    {
        $("#message").css("background-color", "#ff0000");
        $("#message").text("Not a valid order number...");
    }
    $("#message").fadeOut(2500);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submitSearch").click(function(e){

        var formData = $("#labOrderFind").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "labSearch.php",
            cache: false,
            data: formData,
            success: onSuccess
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });


});
```

What I would like to do is onSuccess if data!="NO", POST the formData again to the labOrders.php so that labOrders.php can use it to do more lookups against a db.  I've tried to do this many ways but I've not been successful.  Am I going about this the wrong way?  As long as we can use POST, I'm open to all solutions.

Extra info:
jquery and jquery.mobile are loaded in the head (it's a tablet app).

Maybe stackoverflow needs a noob tag for questions like this.

Comment: Why would you execute a 2nd ajax call instead of just retrieving the data on the first call in place of "no" for valid requests?

Comment: I actually do that.  data either contains a valid order number or "NO".  I made that change this morning but I'm unsure how to POST data to labOrders.php.  Again, if I'm doing this all wrong please let me know.

Comment: @neo4jay, do a new AJAX request from `onSuccess` then, it's the same AJAX call structure

Comment: @Alexander, I tried that first but the results were a bunch of JS code in the resulting URL.  It was odd so I thought I must be doing it wrong and went down another path.  I'll try again.

Comment: @neo4jay, that one should be your question, not this intent of question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem.  Below is my solution in case someone else runs into a problem like this in the future.

I found this function.

```
function post(URL, PARAMS) {
    var temp=document.createElement("form");
    temp.action=URL;
    temp.method="POST";
    temp.style.display="none";
    for(var x in PARAMS) {
        var opt=document.createElement("textarea");
        opt.name=x;
        opt.value=PARAMS[x];
        temp.appendChild(opt);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(temp);
    temp.submit();
    return temp;
```

}

I then slightly modified my onSuccess function:

```
    function onSuccess(data, status)
{
    data = $.trim(data);
    if(data != "NO")
    {
                    post("labOrders.php", {
                        orderNum:data
                    })
    }
    else
    {
            resetTextFields();
        $("#message").css("background-color", "#ff0000");
        $("#message").text("Not a valid order number...");
    }
    $("#message").fadeOut(2500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
location.href="labOrders.php";
```

to

```
$("#labOrderFind").submit();
```

The 'action' of "labOrderFind" must be 'labOrders.php'
and if you're going to use the order number in labOrders.php, do not reset it's value.